# Once a href (with a class) has been clicked, launch a custom dialog (css custom)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dialog

I have added a class to a selection of links on my website.

Once clicked these links need to launch a custom dialog box.

I would like to change the CSS of this custom dialog box.

Only the links with this class can launch this custom dialog box.

Hopefully this makes sense. Thank you guys

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/erlenmasson/qP8DY/2576/

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/ErlenMasson" target="_blank"> External link </a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
}).addClass("external-link");

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('external-link');
var confirmIt = function (e) {
    if (!confirm('Leaving so soon?')) e.preventDefault();
};
for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-dialog {
}
```

Comment: Are this links parent of the dialog box? Can you put a example code?

Comment: can we see what you've got so far?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erlenmasson/qP8DY/2574/

Answer (score 2):

You can't style these dialogs (called by `alert()`, `confirm()` etc.), it belongs to system, not a browser.

If you want to style it, you should take a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or search for modal dialog, there are tons of tutorials for this on Internet.

(You can also check [Bootstrap' dialogs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals))